androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ConsumedInsetsModifier cannot be cast to androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputModifier
I am facing this an issue when changing from between screen sizes (Tavle, Foldable, Phone) in the Android Emulator:
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ConsumedInsetsModifier cannot be cast to androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputModifier
                                                                                at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.onCancelPointerInput(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:354)
                                                                                at androidx.compose.ui.node.PointerInputModifierNode.onDensityChange(PointerInputModifierNode.kt:102)
                                                                                at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.setDensity(LayoutNode.kt:669)
                                                                                at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.setCompositionLocalMap(LayoutNode.kt:696)
                                                                                at androidx.compose.ui.node.ComposeUiNode$Companion$SetResolvedCompositionLocals$1.invoke(ComposeUiNode.kt:44)
                                                                                at androidx.compose.ui.node.ComposeUiNode$Companion$SetResolvedCompositionLocals$1.invoke(ComposeUiNode.kt:43)
                                                                                at androidx.compose.runtime.Applier.apply(Applier.kt:180)
                                                                                at androidx.compose.runtime.changelist.Operation$UpdateNode.execute(Operation.kt:554)
                                                                                at androidx.compose.runtime.changelist.Operations.executeAndFlushAllPendingOperations(Operations.kt:332)
                                                                                at androidx.compose.runtime.changelist.ChangeList.executeAndFlushAllPendingChanges(ChangeList.kt:88)
                                                                                at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChangesInLocked(Composition.kt:1033)
                                                                                at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChanges(Composition.kt:1064)
                                                                                at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke(Recomposer.kt:669)
                                                                                at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke(Recomposer.kt:576)
                                                                                at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:39)
                                                                                at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:108)
                                                                                at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
                                                                                at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1404)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1415)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1015)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:941)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1389)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8674)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.runtime.PausableMonotonicFrameClock@8f5b374, androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@d02f09d, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@5fe7912, AndroidUiDispatcher@c2938e3]

I use the Resizable API VanillaIceCreame to text on different screen sizes.
According to the error there is no issue in my code, otherwise I would see a reference to a code line in my code.
Hier is the info about Android Studio:
Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-242.23339.11.2421.12550806, built on October 24, 2024
Runtime version: 21.0.3+-79915917-b509.11 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Toolkit: sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit
macOS 15.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Concurrent GC, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 8
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
  ide.instant.shutdown=false
  debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
  ide.experimental.ui=true
  i18n.locale=
  terminal.new.ui=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  com.intellij.marketplace (242.22855.133)
  dev.j-a.swift (1.1.0.354-242)
  tarn.gradle.dependencies (2.0.0)
  com.jetbrains.kmm (0.8.3(242)-5)

What is the exact issue?
In previous version of Android Studio I had not any similar issues.

I just tested using the same setup as you:

Android Studio Ladybug 2024.2.1 | Patch 2
Resizable Emulator
API35 VanillaIceCream

I can't reproduce any crash using a simple demo Compose app when switching between the screen sizes. Please make sure that you have the latest emulator version installed. First, open the SDK Manager in Android Studio:

Then, switch to the SDK Tools tab and locate the libraries related to the emulator:

If any updates are available, install them. Afterwards, delete your old Resizable emulator and create it again.

If the issue persists, try to create an empty new Compose project and run it. If you also get the issue there, then please open up an issue on the Google Issue Tracker. The Resizable emulator is still in experimental state.

@BeniyTec thank you for your answer and also effort trying to reproduce the issue. I always keep my IDEE updated and there might also be a piece of code between many code lines which trigger that issue. Nevertheless I will post this issue on Google Issue Tracker let Google take care of. Thanks again.

@MarkDelphi I found that the SDK tools installed are not updated when you update Android Studio, that's why I thuoght it might be worth a try checking that :) Have you tried creating an empty project and runnning that? Is the issue also appearing then?
